# Yii2 facebook login

Tags: facebook, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to integrate facebook login in my website. I created the app and i got the app id and app secret. After successfull login in facebook, how should i got the return data. Here is my code.

```
 public function actions() {
    return [
        'error' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
        'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
        'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
        'auth' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
        'successCallback' => [$this, 'oAuthSuccess'],
        ],
    ];
}

public function oAuthSuccess($client) {
    // get user data from client
    $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
    print_r($userAttributes);
    exit;


  }
```

here is my config/main.php:

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
    'facebook' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
        'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
        'clientId' => '****',
        'clientSecret' => '*****',
        'attributeNames' => ['name', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
       // 'returnUrl' => 'https://www.example.com/site/auth',
    ],
    ],
],
```

Is it required to give any return url?
After login to the facebook it returned to a not found page. What is the issue?

Comment: what url it shows you for not found ?

Comment: https://www.example.com/site/auth?code=*******. This url shows not found.

Comment: show the code for the view, from where you open the authentication dialog by clicking on the facebook button

Comment: After successfull login how will it redirect or redirect to which action?

Comment: <?= \yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget(['baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth']]) ?> this is my code for the view. When i click on the fb icon,it shows a popup where i can enter my facebook username and password. and i click the submit button it redirects to error page